# Calling the appropriate setStatusBarHidden per iOS version

Tags: iphone, statusbar

Today my app approved, but I got emails from users says it crash. I figured out that

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
```

Is the problem, Because users have firmware 3.1.x this API is not working and app crash.

So I have replace it with

```
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]>=3.2)
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    else 
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

My questions...

Is what I did the best solution?

Why XCODE did not warn me that SetStatusBarHidden withAnimation is not in 3.0 while I set my Traget OS firmware 3.0?

Do I have to check on every API to see if it is working with my Target OS?

Thank you

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'd recommend you to use the following snipplet of code instead of checking against the version of the os, rather check if a selector is currently available.

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(setStatusBarHidden: withAnimation:)])
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
else 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

Use only

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

instead of

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

It works with no warning

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if you are compiling with the 4.0 SDK using the simulator, the above solutions will give you a warning, which by default is treated as an error:

```
warning: 'setStatusBarHidden:animated:' is deprecated (declared at /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:267)
```

So you can either set 'Treat warnings as errors' to false in the build settings, or you can use macros to conditionally include the correct code. I have my base SDK set to Device 4.0, my target os is 3.1, and am using this macro:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED > 30100
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:YES];
#else
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
#endif
#endif
```

Note that setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation came available in 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably the best thing to do, other than limiting your application to >=3.2. anyways, you xcode should give you a warning that the SetStatusBarHidden withAnimation message is not supported ("may not respond to").

Comment: I did not get the warning because I set the IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to 3.0 not the BASE SDK. On the last xcode Version 3.2.3 I only see firmware 4.0 and 3.2 as base SDK all others are missing.