# Xcode warning when using deprecated setStatusBarHidden method

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I found this on StackOverflow regarding the problem, but was not able to solve my problem.

[Calling the appropriate setStatusBarHidden per iOS version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028255/about-setstatusbarhidden)

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(setStatusBarHidden: withAnimation:)])
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:NO];
else 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

I set my OS deployment target to 3.0, yet I still recieve the warning 'setStatusBarHidden:animated: is deprecated'

I'd like to have no warnings if possible in the project, and not a hack that removes it.  Is there a way I'm supposed to set up the project to remove this warning?

I've set the project base SDK to 4.0.
And the target Base SDK to 4.0, deployment target SDK to 3.0.

I made these settings for 'All configurations'

Update:  Apparently the warning only appears in the simulator, not when set for Device.

Comment: In `setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:` the `withAnimation:` part doesn't take a `BOOL`, it takes a `UIStatusBarAnimation` constant. [See here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setStatusBarHidden%3awithAnimation%3a)

Answer (score 4):

A deprecation warning means that you are using something that will not be supported in the future. This particular syntax is listed as deprecated [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html). You get rid of the warning by not using the deprecated method. You should be using [setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:): instead

If you wish to support this functionality on both 3.0 and 3.2+ then you will have to write conditional code based upon the target version. There is some useful information on pre-processor macros and functions to help you [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/07/tips-tricks-for-conditional-ios3-ios32.html).

Comment: But that doesn't work with OS 3.0 devices.  It crashes my iPod touch with OS 3.1.3 for unrecognized selector.

Comment: I'm not an Iphone developer but I think you have to check if a particular feature from a later version exists before using it by calling respondsToSelector (From your link above)

Comment: Harsh down-vote BTW. The answer was correct as it stood. Anyhow edited with some more info.

Comment: BTW, I didn't down-vote.  Someone else did.  Also, there should be a way to do it in code, without preprocessor directives?  How can apple allow the creation of 3.x apps, and a deprecated method is required for full screen in 3.x, with no way to use it on an app compatible with both 3 & 4?  Needing macros just doesn't seem....right

Comment: Updated above, apparently this only affect the simulator, not when set for device.  Strange.

Answer (score 3):

This might help, if you develop for older devices, not sure about the last but it looks nice:

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(setStatusBarHidden: withAnimation:)])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
}
else if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(setStatusBarHidden: animated:)])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
}
else if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(setStatusBarHidden:)])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
}
```

However, the problem came up after I switched Devices from iPhone to Universal and back to iPhone. Took me a while to realize that Deployment Target was changed to 4.3, so changing it back to 3.0 made the warning disappear.

Answer (score 1):

you can perform it like this to overcome the warnings at once

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
(void) methodUsingDeprecatedStuff { //use deprecated stuff }
```

or

Just paste this line before using your deprecated stuffs every time to avoid warnings

#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wdeprecated-declarations"

this will remove the warnings.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Don't forget to put `#pragma clang diagnostic pop` after the deprecated code to turn warnings back on