# -setStatusBarHidden:animated: is deprecated

Tags: iphone

At the start of my app, the status bar is hidden, due to the Info.plist setting called `Status bar is initially hidden`. Later on, I want to show the status bar using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

but I get a warning saying that the function is deprecated. Does anybody know what the new function is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [About setStatusBarHidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028255/about-setstatusbarhidden)

Comment: The documentation clearly says which method to use: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setStatusBarHidden:animated:

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW70) is the new method, which takes a [`UIStatusBarAnimation`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIStatusBarAnimation) instead of a `BOOL`, so you can choose what animation is used to hide the status bar.

Answer (score 3):

It is:

```
- (void)setStatusBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden withAnimation:(UIStatusBarAnimation)animation
```

See the [UIApplication class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:) for more info.

If you are trying to write code for both iOS 3.x and iOS 4.x, you are going to run into a further issue that the new method is not available in the old iOS.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853184/suppressing-line-specific-xcode-compiler-warnings) for further info.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your AppDelegate.m

```
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;
```